# ¿Como se hace en Mysql para filtrar por fecha (día, mes, año y hora) si solo quiero filtrar los resultados solamente por un mismo día y mes

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo en SQL ,espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo una Tabla en MYSQL con pedidos y ventas según la hora, día, mes y año en que se hicieron y necesito filtrar todos las ventas que se hicieron entre marzo y abril y luego sacar los que se hicieron en un mes (del 15 de marzo al 15 de abril)

intenté esto:

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE date_add BETWEEN '05-15' AND '06-15'
```

y esto:

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(orderDate)=5 AND MONTH(orderDate)=6
```

pero me da error ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer caso,  puede utilizar [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para obtener el formato de día y mes para luego hacer la comparación.

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_add,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '05-15' AND '06-15';
```

Igual podría funcionar para el segundo caso utilizando la misma función

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_add,'%m') BETWEEN '05' AND '06';
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono de maravilla. una ultima pregunta ¿se puede meter un count para contar los registros resultantes?

Comment: @mati sí, en lugar de `select * from ventas ...` sería `select count(*) from ventas  ...`